# If a Dubai hotel sponsors my visa am I required to stay there?

Tags: visas, hotels, dubai

My colleagues and I will be going to Dubai next week and our visas are currently in process by the hotel where we are booked at.
Recently there has been a change of plans that may require a change in hotel.

My question is are we required to stay at the hotel that sponsors our visa, or are we free to change hotels once we get the visas?
I am asking because in the electronic visa it is written down who our sponsor is.
I do not know whether or not Dubai immigration is connected to hotel reservations, and whether it would be trouble if they find out that I am not staying at the same hotel as my sponsor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check with the hotel, not immigration.

The hotel can report you as absconded and this will cause you all kinds of trouble when you exit the country.

To be perfectly safe, I would check-in to the hotel that had the reservation, and then check-out later for my other hotel.

There are rumors that hotels do report guests to immigration - but this is a post-fact reporting issue and as far as I know, there is no live link between the hotel and immigration.

The reason I mention this is because frequently I have flown in for a day trip where I don't book a hotel and this has caused no problems with immigration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this case checking with the hotel is right.